# Optimized raid 0 configuration for Amazon EC2 hi1.4xlarge

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mdadm, raid0

How do I know what is the best configuration for RAID 0 (mdadm create options) between the to ephemeral drives?

Comment: please do some research first and show what you've found before you ask such a short question. for example, google "amazon ec2 ebs raid 0 benchmark".

Answer (score 0):

you can use mdadm in a normal way, the same as on any other linux. You should also try increasing the IO on your EBS disks, depending on the application it might be cheaper to have a higher IO disk than a raid.